# How do I fulfil annotations with my custom text within interactive pdf file using Swift and PDFKit?

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

I have an interactive pdf file, and all I need is to fulfil its text fields within my ios app. It may be any tool, native or not.

Simply it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

I need to fulfil that array with any data. Is it possible at all?

USing `PDFKit` it looks like this:

```
let url = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "a", ofType: "pdf")!
let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: url)
let document = PDFDocument(url: path) //PDFDocument
let page1 = document!.page(at: 0)! //PDFPage
let page2 = document!.page(at: 1)! //PDFPage
let annotations = page1.annotations //[PDFAnnotation] count is 380, voilaa;)
```

Here I have access to the every annotation/textfield. But the question is:

**How do I fill annotations with my custom strings?**

I try the following thing:

```
    for annotation in annotations {
        annotation.setValue("bb", forAnnotationKey: PDFAnnotationKey.textLabel)
        annotation.setValue("cc", forAnnotationKey: PDFAnnotationKey.contents)
    }
    let name = "output.pdf"
    let output = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(name)
    document.write(to: output)
    let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [output], applicationActivities: nil)
    present(controller, animated: true)
```

Then I save it to iBooks... and... it is empty;) Why? Where are my `bb` or `cc` labels?

Comment: What do you mean fulfil the textfields? Do you want all the textfields to be filled with the same kind of data?

Comment: Yes, I have a data stored within my app. Now I need to use above pdf file and fulfil textfields with these data. It is always the same type/kind, but not the same content.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `widgetStringValue` for your `PDFAnnotation`:

```
for annotation in document.page(at: 0)!.annotations {
    annotation.widgetStringValue = "value"
}
```